# Hyosung GT650R Comet Radiator

Tags: motorcycle, radiator, replace

So lately my bike started overheating.

I thought the radiator filter was dirty, or needed more coolant so I took it to a shop.

The mechanic said I had a liitle hole on it (maybe a stone hit it) so when the bike heated, the gas scaped through it..

And the solution was to replace the whole radiator (+300€ new) because for this model you cant weld it.

I really dont know about this kind of fixment.

[image]

In the picture I show where is supouse to be the hole.

**Is the mechanic solution right? is there any other way to solve this?**

Comment: In my day, you didn't weld radiators, you brazed them.  Try that.  Also, if the hole is small enough, use *Radweld* if that is still on the market.

Comment: @Chenmunka excuse my english, whats the difference between weld and braze?  my translator outputs the same

Comment: Welding is mostly used for steel / iron. Brazing is for copper / brass. Soldering is for tin / gold / silver. The temperatures of each are different due to the melting points. For your radiator, is it aluminium? could be welded if so, but needs to be someone experienced in welding aluminium otherwise you get a big hole!

Comment: @SolarMike ooooh I get it, hahah in my language we have just one word. thanks for the info.

Comment: @lois6b make sure you know who you reply to...

Comment: @SolarMike so sorry, I looked at the comment because im in a hurry right now. thanks!

Comment: Looking at your image, then a long time ago we would crush the tube and braze or solder it to stop the leak. Now however, the tubes are so fine and the radiators so close to the minimum size that it is not advisable. Sorry, start saving...

Comment: Did the mechanic say *why* it can't be welded/brazed?

Comment: @raydowe too thin the tubes

Comment: Does it look significantly different than the GV650? Leaking rads seem to be a common problem with them, and they've been fixed with success. I'd be curious to know what the repair places say: http://korider.com/index.php?topic=25868.0

Comment: @raydowe I was considering all the options... I think the best solution is a brand new radiator. I bought the bike 1 year ago, second hand bike, and its the first major problem so I think having a new one will prevent future problems with the radiator... And I will put some kind of protection to it xDD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to braze the radiator and fix the hole, but it depends on how big it is and where it is. Would be worth finding a few repair places nearby and checking with them. Send good quality photos with something like a coin for scale so they can get an idea of the damage.

It might be easiest and cheapest to just replace it. Check local bike breakers or online for a used radiator. You should be able to [find one for a reasonable price](http://www.ebay.com/itm/05-HYOSUNG-GT650R-COMET-ENGINE-RADIATOR-MOTOR-COOLER-COOLING-RADIATER-/252682202107?hash=item3ad5086bfb:g:NnUAAOSwA3dYUavg&vxp=mtr).

Avoid the temptation to use the "leak-fix-in-a-can" solutions at auto parts stores. They'll make a mess of your cooling system that will be impractical to ever reverse.

Comment: thanks for answering. with "leak-fix-in-a-can" you mean the Radweld product recomended in the comments ?

Comment: Not familiar with that one specifically, but those are the types of products I was referring to. Your coolant system has lots of little passages all over the inside of the engine. If something does gunk it up, you're not going to get it cleaned out.

Comment: I read a bit more and it seems that the liquid "leak-fix" just react in contact with air, so maybe internal passages are not involved... can this be true?

Comment: That's the idea, yes. You mix it in with your coolant, and when some of it leaves the system at the leak, it reacts with air and solidifies. The problem is if you ever get air in your system, or it doesn't do what it's supposed to do, and some of it solidifies inside the system. It's very easy to degrade the system's performance, or block passages entirely. If this happens, there is no way to get it out. I know the idea of fixing this for <$10 is tempting, but the old adage applies here. "If it sounds too good to be true, it probably is."

Comment: The only time I would use something like this is if it's a really old vehicle, and you don't care about it. It will give it a little more life before you bring it to the wreckers. With a little legwork, I'd expect you to be able to get a good used rad for $50-100, which is a much better solution.

Comment: I do care about *her* so I will do whatever assure a long life hehe